# Parse Response from PHP Webservice in android

Tags: php, android, json, web-services

I am trying to consume PHP Web service with JSON in android

I got response data from server as

```
string(170) "["14","Samsung","1","15","Nokia","1","16","Sony Ericson","1","18","LG","1","19","Iphone","1","21","HTC","1","22","Motorola","1","23","Micromax","1","41","BlackBerry","1"]"
```

How should i parse it to show it on a ListView.I am familiar about how to show data on ListView by creating custom adapter but I am unable to parse this output.Please help

I followed this tutorial to access PHP Web Service

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php
Give me some reference.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you...

Alos I would like to know what is the proper format of JSONArray generated at php side ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid but weird json response. 
When you parse this json you will get 27 values. 
14, samsung, 1, 15, nokia... 
But it seems every 3 item is an object like 
"14,samsung,1"
"15,nokia,1". 
And that json doesn't reflect that.

With an online json parser like this, you can see what result you can:

`http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/`

And you can parse that json like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
int counter = 0;
boolean first = true;
String json = "[\"14\",\"Samsung\",\"1\",\"15\",\"Nokia\",\"1\",\"16\",\"Sony Ericson\",\"1\",\"18\",\"LG\",\"1\",\"19\",\"Iphone\",\"1\",\"21\",\"HTC\",\"1\",\"22\",\"Motorola\",\"1\",\"23\",\"Micromax\",\"1\",\"41\",\"BlackBerry\",\"1\"]";
JSONArray getJSONArray;
try {
  getJSONArray = new JSONArray(json);

  for (int i = 0; i < getJSONArray.length(); i++) {

    Log.d("", getJSONArray.getString(i) + "-" + i % 1 + "-" + i % 2);

    if ((first == true && counter == 1) || (first == false && counter == 2)) {
      list.add(getJSONArray.getString(i));
      counter = 0;
      first = false;
    }
    else {
      counter += 1;
    }
  }
}
catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Log your array to see what you got:**

```
for (String item : list) {
  Log.d("list", item);
}
```

**Results:**

```
D/list    ( 1669): Samsung
D/list    ( 1669): Nokia
D/list    ( 1669): Sony Ericson
D/list    ( 1669): LG
D/list    ( 1669): Iphone
D/list    ( 1669): HTC
D/list    ( 1669): Motorola
D/list    ( 1669): Micromax
D/list    ( 1669): BlackBerry
```

**And for the server site:**

Normally that json had to be like this..

```
[
    {
        id: "14",
        brand: "Samsung",
        status: "1"
    },
    {
        id: "15",
        brand: "Nokia",
        status: "1"
    },
    {
        id: "16",
        brand: "Sony Ericson",
        status: "1"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explaination .. this helped me

Answer (score 4):

First of all it is not a valid Json format, Json must have a `label` and is corresponding `value` ex. *"label": "value"*, but still you can parse this string manually
like this

```
String yourString= "["14","Samsung","1","15","Nokia","1","16","Sony Ericson","1","18","LG","1","19","Iphone","1","21","HTC","1","22","Motorola","1","23","Micromax","1","41","BlackBerry","1"]";

yourString= yourString.subString(1, yourString.length()-1);

String[] arrayValue= yourString.split(",");
```

Now you have *arrayValue[0]= "14" arrayValue[1]= "Samsung"* and so on.

Answer (score 3):

looks like a 'stupid-json' array. There is basically no problem, since you see it as a list of Strings. Normally I would suggest to use some JSON classes, but in this special easy case following will be sufficient:

```
String jsonString = "["14","Samsung","1","15","Nokia","1","16","Sony Ericson","1","18","LG","1","19","Iphone","1","21","HTC","1","22","Motorola","1","23","Micromax","1","41","BlackBerry","1"]"
jsonString = jsonString.subString(1, substring.length() -1);
String[] singleValues = jsonString.split(",");
```

this should result in this

```
new String[]{"14","Samsung","1",....}
```

and you can pass that array of String inside your custom ListAdapter (but the default one should be fine, too)

Comment: @Shruti it is valid. look at answer from Nesim Razon. It 'should' be something like this "{"data":["14","Samsung","1","15","Nokia","1","16",...]}